# ProgressBar inside SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a ProgressBar to my row.xml view but I can't seem to make it work I keep getting

```
06-09 12:44:44.802: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1012): java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.ProgressBar is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleAdapter

ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("progress", 10);
arr.add(map);

String [] fieldNames = {"progress"};
int [] fieldIds = {R.id.progress};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arr, R.layout.row, fieldNames, fieldIds);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="5"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleAdapter` does not know how to deal with a `ProgressBar`. Moreover, a `ProgressBar` by itself will be a truly awful list row.

Please put the `ProgressBar` inside of some larger row layout (with a label and such). You will also need to create your own adapter class that will know how to bind data to a `ProgressBar`.

Comment: Thanks. I made my own by extending base adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `SimpleAdapter.setViewBinder()` and bind the progress bar in your `SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder`.  This allows you to use the built-in `SimpleAdapter` functionality for other fields.